# Error: invalid BigNumber value (INVALID_ARGUMENT) when calling quoteExactOutputSingle function

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm encountering an issue while executing the code below. The code is intended to call the quoteExactOutputSingle function from a contract named Quoter. However, I'm getting an error related to an invalid BigNumber value.

```
const { Contract, ethers } = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
// Connect to the Ethereum mainnet via Infura
const RPC_URL = 'ws://172.33.0.6:8546';
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(RPC_URL);

// Define the Quoter contract address and ABI
const QUOTER_ADDRESS = "0x61fFE014bA17989E743c5F6cB21bF9697530B21e";
const quoter_addy = new Contract(QUOTER_ADDRESS, JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./QuoterV2ABInew.json")), provider);

const contractAddress = '0xf8c76dbea329ec4fa987afc514f805b21b249d79';
const desiredAmount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1000000", 18); // 1000000000000000000000000000
const from = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2';
const fee = 10000;
const sqrtPriceLimitX96 = "0";

async function getAmountOut() {
    const params = {
        'tokenIn': from,
        'tokenOut': contractAddress,
        'fee': fee,
        'amountOut': desiredAmount,
        'sqrtPriceLimitX96': '0'
    };
    try {
        const ret = await quoter_addy.callStatic.quoteExactOutputSingle(params);
        console.log(ret);
        return [ret[0], ret[3]];
        // we catch an error because the pool may not exist
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return [null, null];
    }
}

getAmountOut();
```

When executing the code, I receive the following error message:

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:250:21)
    at Function.BigNumber.from (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\bignumber\lib\bignumber.js:239:23)
    at NumberCoder.encode (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\number.js:36:39)
    at C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\array.js:74:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\array.js:60:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\tuple.js:71:33)
    at C:\Users\Joe\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\coders\array.js:74:19 {
  reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'value',
  value: undefined
}
```

I'm unsure how to resolve this error. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct QuoteExactOutputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint256 amount;
        uint24 fee;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }
```

The parameter names and order need to follow the defined struct.

```
  const params = {
    tokenIn: from,
    tokenOut: contractAddress,
    amount: desiredAmount,
    fee: fee,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: "0",
  };
```